# Generate an automatic complete graph in C# WPF application

Tags: wpf

I need to draw automatically a complete graph. the complete graph will depend on the number of nodes enter by the user. The weight between two nodes is assigned randomly. The method have used is inefficient because to draw a graph of nine nodes, the user has to click on the screen nine times. Moreover to draw an edge between two nodes, the user has to right click at most at two nodes to establish the link. I have tried to  look for some online examples of this, but I cannot seem to find anything. This is what I have done so far

CODE

```
    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Label v = new Label();
        v.Content = E;


        Ellipse cir = new Ellipse();
        cir.Width = 16.5;
        cir.Height = 16;

        circ.Stroke = Brushes.MediumAquamarine;
        circ.StrokeThickness = 2;
        CanvasMiddle.Children.Add(circ);

        Point a = e.GetPosition(circ);

        Canvas.SetLeft(circ, a.X-3);
        Canvas.SetTop(circle, a.Y+1);


        Vertex.Add(i, new Tuple<double, double>(a.X, a.Y));

        CanvasMiddle.Children.Add(value);

        Point coordinates = e.GetPosition(v);
        Canvas.SetLeft(v, coordinates.X-5);
        Canvas.SetTop(va, coordinates.Y-5);
            f++;

        i++;
    }
```

// To generate the edge between two nodes

```
private void Window_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

{

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= Node.Count; i++)
        {
            E1 = Node[i].Item1 - 13; a2 = Node[i].Item1 + 13;
            G1 = Node[i].Item2 - 13; b2 = Node[i].Item2 + 13;

            if ((P >= E1 && P <= G1) && (Q >= E1 && Q <= G1))
            {
                ID1[j] = i; 
                j++;



                if (j == 2)
                {
                    Line li = new Line();

                    li.X1 = Vertex[ID1[0]].Item1 + 5;
                    li.Y1 = Vertex[ID1[0]].Item2 + 5;
                    li.X2 =(line.X2-13)+ (Vertex[ID1[1]].Item1 + 5);
                    li.Y2 =(line.Y2) + (Vertex[ID1[1]].Item2 + 5);

                    li.Stroke = Brushes.MediumAquamarine;
                    li.StrokeThickness = 2;

                    Point co1 = e.GetPosition(li);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(li, co1.X+2.78);
                    Canvas.SetTop(li, co1.Y+1.85);


                    CanvasMiddle.Children.Add(li);

                    j = 0;
```

}

Images:
 Here is the link of the specific graph at hand.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJF5K.png

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you would want to simplify it. Are there any special / desired behavioral properties that you didn't talk about? Since clicking 9 times to create 9 nodes seems absolutely normal for me.
Please give more insight on what exact behaviour you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like the computer to generate automatically the complete graph  on the screen. This process might take maximum one minute or two minutes. For example  I have managed to build this complete graph using adjacency matrix, but I don't know how to instruct the computer to represent that graph automatically. I think it will be more efficient than to click on the screen nine times.  If you have more questions, please feel free to ask me.

Comment: Lets see if I understand correctly: You have an input of N points with (x, y) coords and you want them to be drawn on the screen at one go?

Comment: Yes please. I really want to test ant algorithm with at least 50 nodes